# Multiple Dynamically-Added Inputs in HTML Form

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add hidden input fields using JavaScript, but I did/have not achieved the desired result.

I want to add hidden fields to a form when a user selects a value from a dropdown list. The number of dropdown lists are not the same in this and other similar pages, there might be more or less than two.

I want to add a number of hidden fields when the user select value from the first dropdown list, and if he selects another value from another dropdown list I want to add additional hidden fields, and to save all the hidden fields' values.

Example:

```
<select id="s1">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

If the user selects "2", I want to add 2 hidden fields:

```
<select id="s2">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

If the user selects "3" in this second list I want to add three additional hidden fields but saving (preserving) the two hidden fields that was already dynamically added using the "s1" earlier.

Comment: better you can explain in your mother tongue itself. so atleast someone can understand frd.

Comment: I dont see what the point of doing this would be, what is your motivation? You could likely use the value of value="" in a for loop which dynamically adds the hidden fields. So when option value="3" is selected, 3 is passed to a function that adds the input fields. But again, what is the point in adding hidden fields?

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I have no idea what you are asking...but a quick fix could be using proper syntax for HTML.

i.e.

```
<select id"s2">
```

Change to

```
<select id="s2">
```

Comment: not this is the problem, i wrote the code just for example, i want to save the hidden input that i add previous, and adding a new hidden input when i select a value from the second, like this http://www.thimbleopensource.com/tutorials-snippets/multi-ajax-input but with select value

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has the very useful change() function.  So you might write something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#s1").change(function(){
        var field_value = $(this).val();

        // then perhaps:
        for(i = 0; i < field_value; i++){

        }

        // or
        if(field_value == 2){
             // do something 
        }
    });
})
```

Hope thats of some use.  Dukeland has a very good point above as well.